# Is it possible to display results from 2 SQL Statements in this format?

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi All and firstly thanks for looking at this question.

I have 2 SQL Statements that i would like to conbine to deliver the Results in a certain format.

The First SQL finds information for a given Timespan from 3 Tables in a Database:

```
SELECT 
substr(b.platz,4,2)||'-'||substr(b.platz,6,2)||'-'||substr(b.platz,8,3)||'-'||substr(b.platz,11,2) AS "Location",  
to_char(b.INV_DATUM, 'dd.mm.yyyy') AS "DateOfInventory", 
b.INV_ZEIT AS "TimeOfInventory",
a.INV_USR AS "InventoriedBy",
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INVERGEBNIS a WHERE a.invnr = b.lfdnr) AS "NumberOfPIDs",
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INVERGEBNIS a WHERE a.invnr = b.lfdnr AND a.menge_soll != a.menge_ist) AS "NumberOfPIDsAdjusted"
FROM INVERGEBNIS a, INVAUFTRAG b, platz p
WHERE b.LFDNR = a.INVNR 
AND b.platz = p.platz_ID 
AND b.INV_DATUM >= '01.01.2019'
AND b.INV_DATUM <= '31.12.2019'
GROUP BY a.INVNR, Platz, to_char(b.INV_DATUM, 'dd.mm.yyyy'), b.INV_ZEIT, a.INV_USR, b.lfdnr
```

The Result would look somthing like this:

```
   Location     DateOfInventory TimeOfInventory InventoriedBy   NumberOfPIDs    NumberOfPIDsAdjusted

S3-11-021-05    16.10.2019      08:31:17        JeEn            3               0
C1-08-011-04    23.08.2019      14:49:18        JeEn            4               0
K6-04-003-03    13.08.2019      11:06:26        JeRi            1               0
S4-01-002-02    22.08.2019      09:22:55        JeEn            3               1
K1-01-023-04    27.09.2019      12:36:58        JeRi            2               1
C1-02-030-04    28.08.2019      12:18:35        JeEn            5               5
C1-07-014-02    22.08.2019      14:19:10        JeEn            3               0
S4-01-002-01    30.08.2019      12:44:10        JeEn            2               2
```

The second SQL finds results of the NumberOfPIDsAdjusted from the first SQL:

```
    SELECT substr(b.platz,4,2)||'-'||substr(b.platz,6,2)||'-'||substr(b.platz,8,3)||'-'||substr(b.platz,11,2) AS "Location", 
a.ARTIKELNR AS "ArticleNumber",  
a.PALNR AS "PID", 
a.MENGE_SOLL AS "ExpectedQuantity", 
a.MENGE_IST AS "CountedQuantity", 
a.ABWEICH_ABS AS "Difference" 
FROM INVERGEBNIS a, INVAUFTRAG b, platz p
WHERE a.menge_soll != a.menge_ist 
AND a.invnr = b.lfdnr
AND b.INV_DATUM >= '01.01.2019'
AND b.INV_DATUM <= '31.12.2019'
GROUP BY a.INVNR, Platz, a.ARTIKELNR, a.PALNR, a.MENGE_SOLL, a.MENGE_IST, a.ABWEICH_ABS
```

The Result would look something like this:

```
Location        ArticleNumber   PID         ExpectedQuantity    CountedQuantity Difference
C1-02-030-04    290090004       6538190978  0                   24              24
C1-02-030-04    290090004       7636034034  0                   24              24
C1-02-030-04    290090004       4130433752  0                   24              24
C1-02-030-04    290090004       3877101085  0                   24              24
C1-02-030-04    290090004       3970443099  0                   24              24
K1-01-023-04    148055064       1282100556  3                   0               -3
S4-01-002-01    520421012       2101052940  0                   10              10
S4-01-002-01    040331016       1273906464  6                   0               -6
S4-01-002-02    715111012       1286209156  16                  0               -16
```

I am trying to combine the two SQLs so that the results are displayed together with some meaning.
I have tried Joins and Unions but with no success.

If its possible, I am trying to achieve this as a result:

Location        DateOfInventory TimeOfInventory InventoriedBy   NumberOfPIDs    NumberOfPIDsAdjusted

```
Location        DateOfInventory TimeOfInventory InventoriedBy   NumberOfPIDs    NumberOfPIDsAdjusted
        ArticleNumber   PID         ExpectedQuantity    CountedQuantity Difference
S3-11-021-05    16.10.2019      08:31:17        JeEn            3               0
C1-08-011-04    23.08.2019      14:49:18        JeEn            4               0
K6-04-003-03    13.08.2019      11:06:26        JeRi            1               0
S4-01-002-02    22.08.2019      09:22:55        JeEn            3               1
        715111012       1286209156  16                  0               -16
K1-01-023-04    27.09.2019      12:36:58        JeRi            2               1
        148055064       1282100556  3                   0               -3
C1-02-030-04    28.08.2019      12:18:35        JeEn            5               5
        290090004       6538190978  0                   24              24
        290090004       7636034034  0                   24              24
        290090004       4130433752  0                   24              24
        290090004       3877101085  0                   24              24
        290090004       3970443099  0                   24              24
C1-07-014-02    22.08.2019      14:19:10        JeEn            3               0
S4-01-002-01    30.08.2019      12:44:10        JeEn            2               2
        520421012       2101052940  0                   10              10
        040331016       1273906464  6                   0               -6
```

Thanks once again for taking the time to have a look at my question.

JRidge

Comment: Why do you have an`INV_DATUM` (date) column and a separate `INV_ZEIT` (time stored as a string) column? Oracle does not have a `DATETIME` data type and the `DATE` data type always stores year, month, day, hour, minute and second components and you can just use a single column.

Comment: In our database we have 2 columns, the time part of the date column is 00:00:00 and the time is saved in the Time column.

Comment: That is evident from your data; however, my point is that you should not do this and should store the time component in the `DATE` column rather than having the time component of the `DATE` set to `00:00:00` and then having a string in a separate column.